# Add new calculated to group in R

Tags: r

I want to add a new calculated column to my grouped output. The new column's name is WHIP. It is calculated by adding H and BB and then dividing the result by IP.

Here is a sample of the input:
[image]

I was able to get this far with my code:

```
wheeler %>% 
filter(DR<99) %>%    
group_by(DR) %>%
summarise(n = n(), avg_ER = mean(ER, na.rm=T)) %>%
mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2)
```

I tried to add this:

```
summarise(n = n(), avg_ER = mean(ER, na.rm=T), WHIP =((H + BB) / IP)
```

but it did not work. I want the output to look like this:

```
     DR     n avg_ER  WHIP
1     4    11   2.91  1.00
2     5     6   3.17  0.45
3     6     1   7.00  1.33
```

Comment: Do you want the WHIP value row-by-row? So row 1 will be WHIP=(1+6)/5=1.4. Using base R `df <- data.frame(ip=1:8,h=sample(1:5,8,T),bb=sample(2:6,8,T));
df$whip <- (df$bb+df$h)/df$ip`

Comment: Yes, after the avg_ER column I want the WHIP column. The output should look like this:
      DR  n   avg_ER  WHIP
1     4    11   2.91       1.00
2     5     6   3.17        0.45
3     6     1   7.00        1.33

Comment: I would like to see all four columns in the output.

Comment: What changes would I need to make to get it to work with my existing code? I'm not sure how to adapt what you wrote.

Comment: On a separate not, how can I get my sample output to appear properly as 4 columns and 4 rows?

Comment: @bjorn2bewild How were you able to get my output and my code to look the way it does?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping WHIP variables in `sum` first. By not doing so you are attempting to calculate WHIP for each observation instead of for the group, so `summarise` won't work.

```
df <- data.frame(ip=1:8, dp = sample(1:4, 8, T), er = sample(1:4, 8, T), 
                 h=sample(1:5,8,T),bb=sample(2:6,8,T)) %>%
  group_by(dp) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), avg_ER = mean(er), 
            WHIP = (sum(h)+ sum(bb)) / sum(ip))
```

Comment: By changing my summarize line to 'summarise(n = n(), avg_ER = mean(ER), WHIP = (sum(H)+ sum(BB)) / sum(IP)) %>%' I got my code to work. (1) In the output, how can I get all the <dbl> values to have 2 decimal places? (2) How can I add columns for IP, H, and BB in the output? They will just contains totals for the respective DR value.

Comment: (1) You can use `round` and (2) you can use `rowSums`

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. From it, I was able to see what I needed to do.

Comment: Below is my code so far. Where would I put rowSums? `wheeler %>% 
    filter(DR<99) %>%
    group_by(DR) %>%
    summarise(n = n(), 
              avg_ER = mean(ER), 
              WHIP = (sum(H)+ sum(BB)) / sum(IP)) %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

I am still confused by what the desired output is exactly. It sounds like you want two things: 1) calculate the row-by-row WHIP, 2) calculate summary stats grouped by DR. This is what I would do to accomplish that.

```r
df <- data.frame(ip=1:8, 
                 dr = sample(1:4, 8, T), 
                 er = sample(1:4, 8, T), 
                 h=sample(1:5,8,T),
                 bb=sample(2:6,8,T))

df$whip <- (df$bb+df$h)/df$ip

df %>% group_by(dr) %>% 
  summarise(mean.er=mean(er),n=n()) %>% left_join(df,.)

  ip dr er h bb      whip mean.er n
1  1  3  3 4  2 6.0000000    2.00 2
2  2  1  2 1  3 2.0000000    2.75 4
3  3  2  4 3  5 2.6666667    2.50 2
4  4  1  3 5  3 2.0000000    2.75 4
5  5  3  1 5  6 2.2000000    2.00 2
6  6  1  4 5  3 1.3333333    2.75 4
7  7  2  1 3  2 0.7142857    2.50 2
8  8  1  2 2  2 0.5000000    2.75 4
```

So you get back your original number of rows, with the WHIP value for each, plus the summary stats based on the DR groups.

Whereas @bjorn2bewild's solution gives you different output.

```r
df %>% group_by(dr) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), avg_ER = mean(er), 
            WHIP = (sum(h)+ sum(bb)) / sum(ip))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
     dr     n avg_ER  WHIP
  <int> <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4   2.75  1.2 
2     2     2   2.5   1.3 
3     3     2   2     2.83
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. You presented your solution in a way that was new to me, and I appreciate it.